# How to pass data to Textbox A in Playwright test using async function enterA?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have extracted function

```
async function enterA(page, a){
  console.log(`Entering ${a}`);
  const textboxA = await page.$('#value1');
  await textboxA.type(a.toString());
}
```

from the Playwright test

```
test('simple form', async ({ page }) => {
  console.log(`Navigating to ${simpleFormUrl}`);
  await page.goto(simpleFormUrl);

  const a = 3;
  const b = 2;
  var expectedResult = a + b;
  
  enterA(page, a);
  
  const textboxB = await page.$('#value2');
  await textboxB.type(b.toString());
```

and Textbox A is no longer filled with data. The value a is correctly passed to the function. When lines from function enterA were inline inside test function, everything worked fine. Filling Textbox B works correctly.

I tried to make function enterA return also the variable page, but the result was the same.

Comment: `await enterA(page, a);`? Playwright discourages `page.$`. Prefer locators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended approach using locator:

```
// Type character by character
await page.locator('#value1').type('Hello World!');
```

Comment: That actually worked. I wonder why similar code does not work: async function readResult(page){
 return page.$('#displayvalue').textContent();
} 
 const resultString =await readResult(page);

Comment: Use of 'Page.$' is discouraged by the playwright team itself and using locator is suggested approach now for all situations .

Comment: Aggrawal Thx for tip. I cannot upvote the answer, as i am on beginner level on SO :)